# Java How can i store a JSON Object or JSON Array in dynamodb without converting it into a string?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, google-ads-api

So the reason I am asking this is that there is a 400kb item size limit and if I stringify the JSON objects they become huge and I have to break them into 5-10 parts or rows for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

A string will take up about a byte per letter, unless your JSON object has a lot of integer values (about 4 bytes per integer) you're probably not going to be saving that much room.

If your JSON object is that big, consider splitting the object into different tables in your database and have a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: So what you are saying is that even if i were to save it as an object it would still most likely be over the 400kb limit?

Comment: Right it could be... Most likely it will be slightly smaller than JSON string representation, but not guaranteed... i.e. Objects like BigInteger, BigDecimal and such take something around 60 bytes or so in serialized mode. There could be some tricks to reduce serialized size, but there is no reason to put that big complexity there. It is better to think about database structure in your case.